# No se puede agregar o actualizar una fila secundaria, una restricción de clave externa Error 1452

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express, sequelize

Estoy teniendo un problema para crear un registro con node y express usando sequelize. Me da este error:

> code: 'ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2',
> errno: 1452,
> sqlState: '23000',
> sqlMessage: 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`base_alta_equipos_v2`.`cuenta`, CONSTRAINT `cuenta_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CuentaTipoAltaId`) REFERENCES `tipo_alta` (`id`))'

Este es el modelo principal

```
function cuenta_data(sequelize,DataTypes){
    let alias = "Cuenta";

    let cols = {
        id:{type:DataTypes.INTEGER,primaryKey:true,autoIncrement:true,allowNull:false},
        fecha_ingreso_mail:{type:DataTypes.DATE,allowNull:false},
        pos_sunmi:{type:DataTypes.STRING(50),allowNull:false},
        distribuidor_nuevo:{type:DataTypes.STRING(50)},
        numero_cuenta:{type:DataTypes.STRING(50)},
        busqueda_x_id:{type:DataTypes.STRING(50)}
    };

    let config = {
        tableName:"cuenta",
        timestamps:false
    };

    let Cuenta = sequelize.define(alias,cols,config);

    Cuenta.associate = (modelos)=>{
        Cuenta.belongsTo(modelos.Tipo_alta,{
            as:"CuentaTipoAlta",
            foreingKey:"CuentaTipoAltaId"
        });
    };

    return Cuenta;
};

module.exports = cuenta_data;
```

y el modelo al que se asocia es:

```
function tipo_alta_data(sequelize,DataTypes){
    let alias = "Tipo_alta";

    let cols = {
        id:{type:DataTypes.INTEGER,primaryKey:true,autoIncrement:true,allowNull:false},
        tipo:{type:DataTypes.STRING(50),allowNull:false}
    };

    let config = {
        tableName:"tipo_alta",
        timestamps:false
    };

    let Tipo_alta = sequelize.define(alias,cols,config);

    Tipo_alta.associate = (modelos)=>{
        Tipo_alta.hasMany(modelos.Cuenta,{
            as:"TipoAltaCuenta",
            foreignKey:"CuentaTipoAltaId"
        })
    };
    
    return Tipo_alta;
};
module.exports = tipo_alta_data;

Probé renombrando a la tabla y al modelo tipoAlta(sin el guión en el medio) y sigue el mismo error. Puede ser otro problema de sintaxis por incompatibilidad de versiones?
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: "el código ahora rompe", cuál es el error? "Hice algunas definiciones", cuáles son? Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).